# Is it reasonable to assume a 1:1 relationship between user stories and use cases?

Tags: user-story, use-case

I am studying user stories and use cases, and I'm curious about ways to combine both these techniques. Basically it seems to me that there is a 1:1 relationship between user stories and use cases, meaning that for each user story, there is a use case related and vice-versa.

I'm not interested in any specific processes, and not even about the type of process (i.e agile versus waterfall). What I want to know is if it is reasonable to assume that this relationship, or at least adopt this assumption as a design practice, even if it is not an absolute law.

Comment: I have no idea if there's an authoritative answer to this sort of thing, but in the flavor of scrum agile my team's trying out, we're using specific use cases as acceptance criteria for a user story, which makes it effectively one-to-many.

Comment: Is your goal to do both or create some sort of hybrid? Doing both could be seen as redundant.

Comment: @JeffO I am just trying to get a better understanding of this stuff. I have no practical goal in view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the book [Software Requirements](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/software-requirements-9780735679665) (p 152):

> Recall that user stories are concise statements of user needs, in
>   contrast to the richer description that a use case provides. In the
>   agile world, a user story sometimes covers the same scope as an entire
>   use case, **but in other cases a user story represents just a single
>   scenario or alternative flow**

So no, there isn't a 1:1 relationship between use cases and user stories.